# Catel getting the view reference in viewmodel

Tags: catel

Is it possible inside a `ViewModel` to have a reference of the view bound to it?
I mean the real view associated just not the type since in a `View/ViewModel` .
I know this breaks the MVVM pattern but in a specific case I have to do.

Answer (score 0):

**Note before reading this answer: the whole point of MVVM is not to access the view in your view models. It's better to put the logic inside a service that combines the vm => v so you can mock it / replace it.**

Now we have done the official statement, Catel manages all its views using the IViewManager. This comes from the [docs](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Finding+the+view+of+a+view+model):

`var viewManager = ServiceLocator.Default.ResolveType<IViewManager>();
var views = viewManager.GetViewsOfViewModel(myViewModel);`

Comment: ok but this gets a view reference of a generic viewmodel not the instantiated one...

Comment: If I am not mistaken, it really contains the instances bound to that specific vm instance (vm.id).

Comment: how it can be as it takes a Type as parameter?

Comment: "public IView[] GetViewsOfViewModel(IViewModel viewModel)" => what type?

Comment: you were right... I was colling it in the Constructor...but it was too early!